# Cannot delete user - running '/usr/sbin/userdel' failed: Child process exited with code 16

Tags: users

When I tried to delete a user using the User Accounts window under Settings, I get the following error message:

`running '/usr/sbin/userdel' failed: Child process exited with code 16`

How can I delete this user?

Comment: What method are you using?

Comment: Through the user accounts window under system settings...I will edit my question to be more clear! Thanks

Comment: What exact command did you put?

Comment: What user are you trying to delete ? Yourself maybe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ensure that the user is logged out of any active sessions.
2. After doing above, close the 'Users Accounts' window and open it again in 'Systems Settings'

If the above did not work run `userdel [username]`. If thqt doesn't work it'll likely be because your user account is used by some process. The error message will give you a process ID (PID).

```
userdel: user [username] is currently used by process [PID]
```

From this, you can figure out what process it is by using `ps -p [PID]`.

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 1742 ?        00:00:09 ruby
```

Once you're happy you can terminate the process, run `pkill` or `kill` to kill it.

```
sudo pkill ruby
```

Run `userdel [username]` again and this time it should work.

Comment: Your answer did not work for me, @dayuloli. Even rebooted and no luck.

Comment: I came across this problem again, Googled it, found my own answer. And it didn't work this time. I will investigate and add to my answer.